Is there a subtle difference between '...would be not [12iib] but something...' and 'would not be [12iib] but something'?
From Rodney Huddleston Geoffrey K Pullum. (2017). The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language. p.827.

The informal way to express the positive counterpart of the claim in
[12iia] would be not [12iib] but something like We have plenty of
time. And to express the positive counterpart of [12iiia] one would
use something like Kim is quite a dancer.

With the usage of 'not...but...', does '...would be not...' have the same status as '...would not be...' ?

I think both mean the same. It would be [not A but B] is the 'correct' version, but in colloquial speech people often put the 'not' in earlier - It would not be A, but (it would be) B.
